# Download a file via Apache Camel SFTP from a directory on a different drive on Windows Server

Tags: java, windows, apache-camel, sftp

I am trying to download a file via Apache Camel sftp route. The file is placed in a directory on a different drive on a Windows Server
The route definition is as follows:

```
from(sftp://hostname:22/../../../D:/FolderName?username=userABC&readLock=changed&delete=true).to(myCustomDirectory)
```

The rest of the options are not shown. The issue is that when I set the readLock to changed, I am receiving exception: GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot list directory: ../../../D:/FolderName. If I remove that option the deletion process is failing.

If the file is placed in a user's home subdirectory everything is fine. But the file is placed on another drive.

Comment: That is because when the connection is established, the default directory is the user home directory C:/Users/userABC. Apache Camel does not allow absolute paths.

Comment: When uploading a file to the same directory, the ../../../ works perfectly fine.